# MKMapCamera pitch-altitude function

Tags: ios, ios7, mkmapview, mapkit

Неу all. I need some help.
I'm working with MapKit and of course my camera can go up and down (zoom in and zoom out).

I want to change MKMapCamera pitch while zooming.
So when the camera is low the pitch will be big (~80) and when camera is high the pitch will be small (0).

Here is the picture, showing what I want to do:

[image]

I tried to create function, that will monitor the altitude and automatically change the pitch:

```
cam_timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval: 0.05 target: self selector: @selector (test) userInfo:nil repeats: YES];

- (void) test
{
    [debug_lbl_1 setText: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", map.region.span.latitudeDelta]];

        map.camera.pitch = 45; // changing pitch
}
```

But when I accessing camera in that function it stopped moving. I mean...I can't move, zoom or make anything with map if I trying to access camera from that function.

So my question is: how can I make function that will change pitch when altitude (zoom level)) changed? Please, I very need some help =(

Comment: Did you get any solution @KaronatoR?

Comment: @Vijay yep. I can't get you the code, but the answer was to add the your own pitch recognizer to the map, and changing the altitude and the pitch of the camera in your own pitch recognizer.

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this in iOS 10 and above by using MKMapCamera and UIView animation

```
mapView.camera = MKMapCamera(lookingAtCenter: pinLocation, fromDistance: 2000, pitch: 0, heading: 0)

let pinLocation = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: latitude, longitude: longitude)

let rotationCamera = MKMapCamera(lookingAtCenter: pinLocation, fromDistance: 2000, pitch: 75, heading: 180)

UIView.animate(withDuration: 10, delay: 0, options: .curveEaseInOut, animations: {
            self.mapView.camera = rotationCamera
        }, completion: nil)
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a timer, I would change the pitch in the `MKMapViewDelegate`'s method `mapView:regionDidChangeAnimated:`.

Comment: This method fired only when gesture finished, so it's impossible to change pitch while user is changing altitude "right now". I'm trying to disable standard map zoom and use pinch recognizer now. Anyway, thanks for answer.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps try using KVO to observe `mapView.region` for changes?